# Button click text insertion

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a jsfiddle example of the problem I've been working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/61/

HTML:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<div>
<button class="buttons">c</button>
<button class="buttons">a</button>
<button class="buttons">t</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
    });

    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        $('input.active').append(cntrl);
    });
});
```

I'm unable to get the button click to insert the clicked character into the textbox in the jsfiddle example. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you replace `append` with `val`, this works for me. By works, i mean clicking a text box and then clicking a button inserts the buttons value into the text box.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lordloh/qgbtydgj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `val()` calls instead of append like so: `$('input').val($('input').val()+cntrl)`. See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7fjgvuhh/

Comment: You don't need to call the same method twice, once inside the other, just use the anonymous function: `$(input).val(function(i,v) { return v + cntrl; });`

Comment: That's interesting, I've never seen that used before - thanks!

Comment: A (somewhat-belated) [illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7fjgvuhh/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to show which button was pressed, you could give your buttons a value attribute (`value="c"`, `value="a"` and `value="t"`) in the HTML and use it in the JavaScript code to add it to the textbox.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YD6PL/67/).

HTML:

```
<input id="one" type="text">
<input id="two" type="text">
<input id="three" type="text">
<div>
    <button id="c" class="buttons" value="c">c</button>
    <button id="a" class="buttons" value="a">a</button>
    <button id="t" class="buttons" value="t">t</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#c').click(function () {
        $('#one').val($(this).val());
    })

    $('#a').click(function () {
        $('#two').val($(this).val());
    })

    $('#t').click(function () {
        $('#three').val($(this).val());
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of the button you should use the `$.text()` function

Here is the correct code

**HTML**

---

```
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<div> 
<button class="buttons">c</button>
<button class="buttons">a</button>
<button class="buttons">t</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active')
    });

    $(".buttons").click(function () {
       var cntrl = $(this).text();
       var existing  = $('input.active').val();
       $('input.active').val(existing + cntrl);
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rua4cn8o/1/

Comment: This doesn't really do what's expected - he wants to append items to each input, but your code does a replace. Also, this doesn't work because the JQuery selector you're using won't match the inputs he provided

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I've updated my code. And i think he is trying to allow all the inputs to have multiple characters. That's why I think he's assigning class "active" to the most recently clicked input, and then appending the character to it.

Comment: And `<input>` elements are void/empty elements; in HTML they don't need to be closed (`<input>`) and in XHTML they're self-closing (`<input />`). Also what's `$.text()`, did you just mean the [`text()` method](http://api.jQuery.com/text/)? There is no jQuery.text() method.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you, I didn't know that. I will update my code accordingly.